# Error when query Empty SQLite DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I am writing an Android App and I have a DB Helper class to do just about anything that is related to a SQLite DB. Name of the class is "ResultsDbAdapter". Following are some info about the DB:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PROJECT_RESULTS";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "projectResults";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//Fields(Columns) for Database
public static final String[] PROJECT_RESULTS_FIELDS = new String[] {
    KEY_ROWID,    
    "title",
    "interval", 
    "start",
    "end",  
    "duration",
    "totalHits",
    "itemKeys",
    "keyHits"
};
```

In the ResultsDbAdapter class is a method to query the DB for a specific entry by searching the "title" column.

```
public Cursor fetchByTitle(String pTitle) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, PROJECT_RESULTS_FIELDS, "title" + "=" + pTitle, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    return mCursor;
}
```

The "fetchByTitle" method is then called in the Main Activity with the following snippet of code:

```
final ResultsDbAdapter db = new ResultsDbAdapter (this);
db.open(); //Open and Close methods are also written in the "ResultsDbAdapter" class
final Cursor cursor = db.fetchByTitle(mTitle); //mTitle is the title of the record needed
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
          // do something
 } else {
          //do something else
 }
db.close();
```

The app when first run on an emulator causes an error which I think is because there are no entries. So there is no cursor to return causing the error. Following is the error from logcat:

```
03-07 21:53:51.230: E/SQLiteLog(1158): (1) near "Title": syntax error
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Process: com.jevans.surveybud, PID: 1158
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Title": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, interval, start, end, duration, totalHits, itemKeys, keyHits FROM projectResults WHERE title=My Title
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1238)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.jevans.surveybud.ResultsDbAdapter.fetchByTitle(ResultsDbAdapter.java:141)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.jevans.surveybud.ResultsActivity.saveDb(ResultsActivity.java:163)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.jevans.surveybud.ResultsActivity$1.onClick(ResultsActivity.java:138)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I apologize for the seemingly fundamental question as I am a newbie with Android programming. However, I have been stuck at this for a very long time. Can someone please help to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the error stacktrace says that your resulting sql statement (`SELECT _id, title, interval, start, end, duration, totalHits, itemKeys, keyHits FROM projectResults WHERE title=My Title`) is resulting in a `SQLiteException`

```
03-07 21:53:51.230: E/SQLiteLog(1158): (1) near "Title": syntax error
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Process: com.jevans.surveybud, PID: 1158
03-07 21:53:51.310: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
```

To fix try leveraging the power of the `query()` method arguments so it correctly binds to make functional sql call:

- `selection` (`"title = ?"`)
- `selectionArgs` (`new String[]{ pTitle}`)

Altogether it would look like:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, 
                           PROJECT_RESULTS_FIELDS, 
                           /* selection */ "title = ?", 
                           /* selectionArgs */ new String[]{ pTitle}, 
                           null, null, null);
```

This ought to fix the `SQLiteException` you are having.

HTHs